# How to use own Util classes in more than one Microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a project which is based on Microservices (Spring Boot applications).
I have quite a lot of "Util" classes and Base classes and I'm searching for the best solution to use them in my Microserviceses.

For the sake of simplicity let's say I have created a StringUtil and I have created a CrudService interface and I want to use them in 5 different Microservices.

I would like to ask your opinion about the solution for this, let's say I'm searching for the "Best practice".

Some options I have in my mind:
 - Duplicate the util classes in the Microservices (horrible solution, maintenance hell)
 - Create a separate project for these util classes, build, install it and use it as a dependency in other projects.
 - Publish to a central repository (like Nexus) so the other services can use it as a dependency.

All recommendation and advice are very welcome.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: `Create a separate project for these util classes, build, install it and use it as a dependency in other projects.` - this is the only reasonable solution

Comment: Duplicate code inside one microservice is not acceptable but duplicate code from one microservice to another is not a violation.  Always prefer as possible total decoupling. Maybe you don't need same features everywhere. Sharing something between microservices is against the main idea of this architecture type.

Comment: as people have pointed out, make a lib, but keep the lib clean. Only relevant classes, and static util methods that dont change that often.

Comment: Thank you guys. So as I see you guys prefer to have a seperate project and use it as a dependency.
Are you using the host (meaning only install it locally), or using it through a central repository manager?